# How to work on cpp project managed by CMake?

Tags: c++, gcc, cmake

I am doing realsense depth camera development. I am more familiar with Python.

When using cpp, I am always confused about the cache variables and the dependencies.
Most projects use CMake to manage the package. Yet this posed me a problem: how could I know those library name ? I mean the cache variables, like `${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS}`, `${PCL_LIBRARIES}`, `${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}`.
For example, the following is an error I met: **Undefined reference to symbol `glEnable`**. I think this is a linking error. But how could I know exactly which library I should link to ? In this case, is it openGL or gl or glfw ?

```
$ make
[ 89%] Built target glfw
[ 94%] Linking CXX executable rs-pointcloud
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/rs-pointcloud.dir/rs-pointcloud.cpp.o: undefined reference to symbol 'glEnable'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

1. How to know those cache variables for each package ?
2. How to find out those dependent libraries and link them properly ?
3. Or in general, what is the correct way to develop a cpp project ?

Comment: Error message `cannot find -l{GLFW_LIBRARIES}` means that someone writes `{GLFW_LIBRARIES}` instead of `${GLFW_LIBRARIES}`. As for knowing correct variable, read the documentation for that package.

Comment: Right, thanks. I missed the `$`.

Comment: For variables there is a standard naming scheme but I still google for the docs or if `CMake` has a finder I look at the documentation directly

Comment: I believe the new error means you need  to link to GL. There is a finder for it [https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.10/module/FindOpenGL.html](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.10/module/FindOpenGL.html)